# How to install/run premake4

Tags: macos, installation, premake

I am trying to install premake4 on mac osx but I cannot find any documentation and any help anywhere. I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

I have downloaded/saved `premake-4.4-beta5-macosx.tar.gv` file and when I double clicked on it, it gave me a file named premake4. When I double clicked on that it opened a page (a terminal if I am not mistaken) that contains the following:

```
Last login: Day Mon  * **:**:** on ******
/Users/******/Downloads/premake4 ; exit;
*****-**********:~ ******$ /Users/******/Downloads/premake4 ; exit;
Type 'premake4 --help' for help
logout

[Process completed]
```

I cannot type or change anything on this. I tried typing 'premake4 --help' without single quot in the terminal but it says command not found.
I don't know what else to do. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to read up on how to use command line applications on Mac OS X. Here's [a Treehouse article to get you started](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line).

The "command not found" message is because the Premake executable is probably sitting in your Downloads folder, which isn't on the list of paths that are searched to find programs. This might work better

```
~/Downloads/premake4 --help
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I forgot to reply sooner. Of course I was in the wrong directory. :/ Also what I had to do was to copy the file from download and put it into the /usr/bin so it could run the file. Now it works and everything is fine. :D